# Adding EditText over a canvas in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android. I need to add text over canvas when the user clicks on it.An edittext should popup and when the user is done editing, the text in the edittext combines with the imageview bitmap .I need help in getting an edittext over the imageview, where the user can enter text.I also need to be able to move the edit text around the imageview

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  Where are you stuck ?  we're note writing code for you here ;)

Comment: Hi,i just need to know how to add editText over an imageview.I know how to add text to a position programmatically.I just need to know,how to do it through the UI.

Answer (score -1):

The way you can put a view over another one is to put them in a `FrameLayout`

like in this example :

```
<FrameLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
 android:layout_height="math_parent"
 android:layout_width="math_parent" />

       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/textView2" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:src="@drawable/yourDrawable"/>

       <EditText

               android:id="@+id/EditText1" 
               android:layout_height="50dp" 
               android:layout_width="200dp" 
               android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
               android:text="" 
               android:textsize="15dp" />

</Framelayout>
```

As seen in this [blog post](http://www.pavanh.com/2013/04/android-framelayout-example.html)

As you can see, I used  margins to position the EditText over the image.

```
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
```